# Checkbox SelectedItem Text to Linq Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I built an ASP.net usercontrol and I am trying to get the text from the checkbox to pass to the database. My problem is I keep getting an error on submission with the method I use. Here is what I used:

```
            ResidenceHallInspection rhi = new ResidenceHallInspection();
            rhi.versionId = version.id;
            rhi.submitDate = DateTime.Now;
            rhi.CheckInOrOut = ddlCheck.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.StudentId = txtStudentId.Text;
            rhi.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            rhi.MiddleName = txtMiddleName.Text;
            rhi.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            rhi.Walls = chbxWalls.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Windows = chbxWindows.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Blinds = chbxBlinds.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Couch = chbxCouch.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomCouch = chbxCRCouch.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomChair = chbxCRChair.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Doors = chbxDoors.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Carpet = chbxCarpet.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Ceiling = chbxCeiling.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomCounter = chbxCRCounter.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Cabinet = chbxCabinet.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Phone = chbxPhone.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Bed = chbxBed.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Desk = chbxDesk.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.DeskChairs = chbxDeskChair.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Tub = chbxTub.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Vanity = chbxVanity.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Notes = txtNotes.Text;
            rhi.Building = txtResHall.Text;
            rhi.ApartmentNumber = txtSuitNo.Text;
            rhi.BedSpace = txtBedSpace.Text;

             house.AddToResidenceHallInspections(rhi);
            house.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: What is the error, and where is it occurring?  Are you sure you're passing all of the data for required fields back?  Maybe one is missing.

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: I added everything that is required @BrianMains None of the checkboxes are required. I actually tested this without the checkboxes and it worked but with them it just sends me to my error page.

Comment: @justin.chmura i dont see an error really it just goes to my error page. I tested with and without the checkbox items from the form and only got it bypassing and going to the error page when i added the checkbox items

Comment: I mean, I often experience that error when I don't supply a value to a property on the "rhi" object that's required in the database.  You do get an error for that reason sometimes.  I'm trying to theorize one more way there was a problem.  Anyway, are you logging the error?  If not, could you log the error when redirected and let us know?

Comment: it seems like the error was with the checkbox. I just replaced them with dropdown for nwo

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see more information, such as the error you received, and possible the code and/or HTML for the custom user control.  However, there are a couple of possibilities which seem likely.  One is that your SelectedItem property may be `null`, which would cause an `ObjectReferenceException` to occur.  Another is that Text itself is null, and that your database doesn't allow a null value for one or more of the fields you're assigning.

You can get a better answer than this rather vague one if you provide more information.

Comment: I havent seen an error really. It just goes to my error page. I tried every way of seeing the error and none successful. I also tested with and without the checkbox fields and only got errors when i added those

Comment: A quick and dirty way to find out what the exception is would be to wrap the code from your original post in a try/catch block, like this:  
    try {
    ...code...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

Comment: I tried that initially but it doesnt print out the error. @StevenWestbrook

Comment: after attempting a different approach: I got this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Good, that means that something - maybe your SelectedItem property - is never getting assigned.  Look up ObjectReferenceException to get a better idea of what to do; you'll have to do some digging through your code.

Comment: I get that after i did this:  if (chbxWalls.Enabled == true)
            {
                walls = chbxWalls.SelectedItem.Text;
            }

Comment: and this:  rhi.Walls = walls;

Comment: So i am not quite sure where something got lost